# `BulkWrite error :: norepl` mongodb php BulkWrite

Tags: php, mongodb

I getting this is exception in my application, and don't understand why. This exception throw in for one collection, over collection not throw this exception, with processed `insert()`,`update()`, or `delete()`

```
/**
 * insert to mongo db method
 * @param $dataArray
 * @param $collection
 */
static function insert($dataArray, $collection) {

    $connect = Core_Model_Mongo::getConnect();

    $write = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite();
    $writeConcern = new MongoDB\Driver\WriteConcern(MongoDB\Driver\WriteConcern::MAJORITY);

    $write->insert($dataArray);
    $connect->executeBulkWrite(
        Config_Db::getConf()['mongodb']['db'].'.'.$collection,
        $write,
        $writeConcern
    );
}
```

end get connect method

```
/**
 * @return \MongoDB\Driver\Manager
 */
static function getConnect() {
    if(!is_null(self::$_connect)) {
        return self::$_connect;
    }
    self::$_connect = new \MongoDB\Driver\Manager(Config_Db::getConf()['mongodb']['connect']);
    return self::$_connect;
}
```

data save in collection success full, and this exception not take `insert()`,`update()` and other methods. I temporary resolve this question by try catch block

```
try {
  // my code 
} catch(MongoDB\Driver\Exception\BulkWriteException $error) {
  Core_App::log(var_export($error,true));
}
```

but this is resolve not correct because I need application without any exception,error,notice, and over log level error.

Comment: Add your code please

Comment: @TungD.Nguyen I'm adding

Comment: I temporary resolve my question by log exception to file in `try catch` block but this question is open, I need know why this is exception throw?

Comment: The error should be self explanatory. You are setting a `WriteConcern` for a majority on a "ReplicaSet", but the error is thrown when you are not in fact connected to a ReplicaSet. You should not hard code these things anyway. Ref: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/VF_6g9OcLMM